# Add an array within an array list Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hello community have a query, the issue is that I have a method that consulted the database, which invokes the method assume time parametrically.

As I commented'm using the PHP framework CodeIgniter, the question is this once consulted and loaded the first list of arrays, called: **$listSubPrim**

I want that list of arrays, add another array that is in the list **$listSubSecu**, but the issue is that I notice that does not work the way I want, although the method add **array_push**

***principal_model.php***

```
<?php
class Principal_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, $nivelmenu) {
        try{
            $sql = 'SELECT ICODMAEMENU, ICODROL, VDESMAEMENU, VDESICONO, VDESIDMAEMENU, ';
            $sql = $sql.'ICODPADMENU, VDESCOMAND, SIORDPRIORIDAD, ICODSUBMENU, BACTIVO ';       
            $sql = $sql.'FROM TABMAEMENU ';
            $sql = $sql.'WHERE ICODROL = ? ';
            $sql = $sql.'AND BACTIVO = ? ';     
            switch ($nivelmenu) {
                case NIVEL_SUB_MENU_PRIMARIO:
                    $sql = $sql.'AND ICODPADMENU IS NULL ';
                    $sql = $sql.'ORDER BY ICODMAEMENU ';
                    break;
                case NIVEL_SUB_MENU_SECUNDARIO:
                    $sql = $sql.'AND ICODPADMENU IS NOT NULL ';
                    $sql = $sql.'AND ICODSUBMENU IS NULL ';
                    $sql = $sql.'ORDER BY SIORDPRIORIDAD ';
                    break;
                case NIVEL_SUB_MENU_TERCIARIO:
                    $sql = $sql.'AND ICODPADMENU IS NOT NULL ';
                    $sql = $sql.'AND ICODSUBMENU IS NOT NULL ';
                    $sql = $sql.'ORDER BY SIORDPRIORIDAD ';
                    break;
            }
            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($icodrol, ESTADO_ACTIVO));
            return $query->result_array();
        } catch(Exception $e){
            log_message('debug', $e->getMessage()); // use codeigniters built in logging library
            show_error($e->getMessage()); // or echo $e->getMessage()
        }           
    }

    function obtenerPermisosMenu($icodrol) {
        try{
            /* Obtenemos el listado de SubMenus Primarios de toda la lista */
            $listSubPrim = $this->obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, NIVEL_SUB_MENU_PRIMARIO);
            /* Obtenemos el listado de SubMenus Secundarios de toda la lista */     
            $listSubSecu = $this->obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, NIVEL_SUB_MENU_SECUNDARIO);

            /* Obtenemos el listado de SubMenu de asociado al SubMenu primario */           
            foreach ($listSubPrim as $pri) {
                $listSubMenuItem = array();
                foreach ($listSubSecu as $sec) {
                    if($sec['ICODPADMENU'] == $pri['ICODMAEMENU']) {
                        array_push($listSubMenuItem, $sec);
                    }               
                }
                if (count($listSubMenuItem) > 0) {
                    array_push($pri, $listSubMenuItem);
                }               
            }           

            /* Obtenemos el listado de SubMenus Terciarios de toda la lista */  
            $listSubTerc = $this->obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, NIVEL_SUB_MENU_TERCIARIO);
            /* Obtenemos el listado de SubMenu de asociado al SubMenu secundario */
            foreach ($listSubPrim as $pri) {
                $listSubSecu = $pri[10];
                if (is_array(listSubSecu)) {
                    foreach (listSubSecu as $sec) {
                        $listSubMenuItem = array();
                        foreach ($listSubTerc as $ter) {
                            if($sec['ICODMAEMENU'] == $ter['ICODSUBMENU']) {
                                array_push($listSubMenuItem, $sec);
                            }               
                        }
                        array_push($sec, $listSubMenuItem);
                    }
                }           
            }
            return $listSubPrim;    
        } catch(Exception $e){
            log_message('debug', $e->getMessage()); // use codeigniters built in logging library
            show_error($e->getMessage()); // or echo $e->getMessage()
        }
    }

}
?>
```

I realize that walking back on the list: **$listSubPrim**

Limited position 10 of the array should be an array, so as indicated in the code.

```
$listSubSecu = $pri[10];
```

I hope you have understood my question.
Basically I want just a list of fixes, with three levels.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to merge two array ?

Comment: it would be helpfull if you just give a demo of your expected array structure.

Comment: Hello friend and I answered my question with an example, if you can please support me with my query in PHP ...

Answer (score 0):

Hello I will explain more clearly the impression the first list of arrays: **$listSubPrim**

```
$listSubPrim = $this->obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, NIVEL_SUB_MENU_PRIMARIO);

$listSubSecu = $this->obtenerPermisosNivel($icodrol, NIVEL_SUB_MENU_SECUNDARIO);

foreach ($listSubPrim as $pri) {
    log_message('debug', '-> '.$pri['ICODMAEMENU'].' - '.$pri['ICODROL'].' - '.$pri['VDESMAEMENU']);                
}
```

I printed the results of a list of arrays, as you will notice:

```
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 16:43:31 --> -> 85 - 2 - Las 20 Mejores Ofertas
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 16:43:31 --> -> 86 - 2 - Ofertas Inteligentes
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 16:43:31 --> -> 87 - 2 - Descuentos Restaurantes
DEBUG - 2015-06-10 16:43:31 --> -> 88 - 2 - Categorias
```

I need you in that row, add the list of array: **$listSubSecu**, for each row that is within the array foreach.

Aya hope I understood.
Thank you.